# Consume json rest web service

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest

How can I read a `json` message in a web service? I have a class `Person` and a list of `Persons`. What I want to do is to update a certain person by using a `PUT` method. So far my `update` method looks like this:

```
   @PUT
   @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   @Path("/update/{id}")
   public Response updatePerson(@PathParam("id") String id, Person p) {
      System.out.println(p.getFirstName());
      Person ps = this.fp.getPerson( id );
      if ( ps != null )
         System.out.println( "Person exists" );
      else {
         System.out.println( "Person doesn't exists" );
      }
      return Response.ok().build();
   }
```

For the client I use `SOAPUI` and I try to send this json message from `soapui` : `{firstName" : "John", "lastName" : "Smith", "age" : "35"}`

I really have no idea how to retrieve that `json` message as a `person` object so I can use those attributes.
Please help me with some ideas.

Comment: No need to retrieve json message - if json conforms to your `Person` model, it will be deserialized to the `p` variable

Comment: Are you getting error messages, exceptions, error status codes? What's not working about your above code? Do you have a JSON provider?

Comment: I get a `500` status. Yes I have `Jackson` provider

Comment: Is there any stacktrace being logged? Often when there is an exception leading to a 500, there will be an exception, and it is normally logged, if not simply printed in the console

Comment: Which **JAX-RS implementations** u r using?

Comment: It looks like Jersey...